# CRM Solution Import Problems

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are setting up Quality Assurance(QA) Environment for our client. There is a solution in the production Organization which is unmanaged. This has to be imported into the QA Organization.

1) We exported the Unmanaged solution from production and tried to import it in our QA test environment Org.
2) It is saying that "Missing Dependencies" exist when importing.
3)When we checked all the components and entites are existing in the solution which we tried to import but still it is raising same error.

Anyone has faced similar problems? Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks,
Abhilash.

Comment: Does the solution hold any workflows? if so do the workflows reference any custom workflow activities? if so you need to make sure your plugin assembly is also added to the solution. Also you can download the error log, use excel to open the file and you should be able to get more information from the second tab.

Comment: Does the QA environment have identical updates applied as production?  If the logs aren't telling you anything I'd try breaking out the production solution into smaller solutions and import these separately to help isolate the problem.